# What makes Custom Ribbon callbacks stop working

Tags: excel, vba, callback, office-addins, ribbon

I have developed an excel Add-Ins which contains additional buttons with different function. My initial code was based on "Ron de Bruin Excel Automation" kit which worked great.  (and I thank him for that).  Recently I have added another group and a button, which worked fine on my excel (365 Excel version 2009), but failed on other machines with the same Excel version. The error was, it could not  find any callbacks. I eliminated all callbacks but one "onAction" which is essential, but the error is still there.
Any help.

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="CustomTab" label="שמאות מקרקעין" insertAfterMso="TabDeveloper">
        <group id="GroupA" label="מידע נדלן רשות המיסים">
          <button id="aButton01" label="יבא נתונים" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="GetExternalDataImportClassic" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton02" label="מזג גיליונות" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="ReviewCombineRevisions" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton03" label="מיין ומחק עמודות" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="CreateQueryFromWizard" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton04" label="שווי מר" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="ConditionalFormattingAboveAverage" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton05" label="התאמת משקל" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="PageScaleToFitScale" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton06" label="הכנה לדוח שומה" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="MacroDefault" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton07" label="תמונת הנכס" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="PictureReflectionGallery" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton08" label="וויסות הורדה אפשרויות" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="StartTimer" size="large" />
          <button id="aButton09" label="מחיר למשתכן" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="TentativeAcceptInvitation" size="large" />
        </group>
        <group id="GroupB" label="תכנה">
          <button id="bButton01" label="הוראות שימוש" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="Help" size="large" />
          <button id="bButton02" label="הזמנת רישיון" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="GroupOmsInsert" size="large" />
          <button id="bButton03" label="עידכון גירסה" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="FillUp" size="large" />
          <button id="bButton04" label="נתוני משתמש" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="ArrangeByAccount" size="large" />
        </group>
        <group id="GroupC" label="נסח טאבו">
          <button id="cButton01" label="PDF" onAction="RunMacro" imageMso="FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment" size="large" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

{

```
Sub RunMacro(control As IRibbonControl)
'PURPOSE: Tell each button which macro subroutine to run when clicked

Select Case control.ID
  
  Case "aButton01": Application.Run "FromRibbon"
  Case "aButton02": Application.Run "MergeSheetsmacro"
  Case "aButton03": Application.Run "CleanColumns"
  Case "aButton04": Application.Run "AddAverage"
  Case "aButton05": Application.Run "Weight"
  Case "aButton06": Application.Run "PrepareReport"
  Case "aButton07": Application.Run "ActivateGoogleView"
  Case "aButton08": Application.Run "GrabRegul"
  Case "aButton09": Application.Run "MechirLamishtaken"
  
  Case "bButton01": Application.Run "HelpForm"
  Case "bButton02": Application.Run "LicenseRequest"
  Case "bButton03": Application.Run "UpgradeVersion"
  Case "bButton04": Application.Run "PersonalData"
  
  Case "cButton01": Application.Run "ConvertPDF2Excel"
  
 End Select
    
End Sub
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you show the `onLoad` Code resp. why is no `onLoad` in `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">`

Comment: Worked a long time without, will look for instructions how to add onLoad.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the purpose of the omLoad callback. I see not apparent reason for that. I don't want to change any buttons.

Comment: Maybe there is another way to "talk" with the ribbon but onLoad passes a ribbon parameter to the callback procedure as the Ribbon loads. This enables the associated code to store a reference to the Ribbon for later use and allows you to dynamically update the Ribbon.

Comment: Ok, I tested your XML Code and also added some VBA code in my test file. This is working for me. So, `onLoad` is only needed in case you want to invalidate controls etc. what you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial an error process I found the reason to the effect . 64 bit vs. ,32 bit Office .
I have used some dll functions which were not properly defined for 64 office. As a result it corrupted the code.